# Row-echelon form question about a solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix in row echelon form:

\begin{matrix}
  x_1 & x_2 &x_3 & \\ 
  1 & 0 & -1.417 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & -.917 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{matrix}.

The solution says

\begin{matrix}
  1.417x_3  \\
  .917x_2 \\
  x_3 
 \end{matrix}.

I read this to mean that $x_3$ is the free variable, able to be anything. $x_1$ should be 1.1417 of $x_3$. However, shouldn't the second value be in terms of $x_3$ as well? Shouldn't it be $x_2= .917x_3$?

Solution comes from: http://www.calpoly.edu/~brichert/teaching/oldclass/f2002217/solutions/solutions1.pdf

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, it should be $x_2= .917x_3$ and $x_3$ is a free variable.

Comment: Yes.  It's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. 
set $x_3 = t$, then

$x_2 = .917 t$ 
$x_1 = 1.417t$, so 
 
$x = \begin{bmatrix} 1.417 \\ .917  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}t : t\in \mathbb{R}$